# Generate datetime when entry made in cell

Tags: excel, vba, datetime

I have code which should display the date in column A whenever something is entered in column B.

I enabled macros in security settings.

The VBA code is in `ThisWorkbook` under the project because I want the same thing to happen on every sheet.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, _
 ByVal Source As Range)
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim Rng As Range
Dim xOffsetColumn As Integer
Set WorkRng = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("B:B"), Target)
xOffsetColumn = -1
If Not WorkRng Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each Rng In WorkRng
        If Not VBA.IsEmpty(Rng.Value) Then
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).Value = Now
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy, hh:mm:ss"
        Else
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).ClearContents
        End If
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Ahh, I see that now thank you. I've adjusted the original code but it still does not execute?

Comment: Check that events are enabled: `Application.EnableEvents = True` in the Immediate Window. Also, change `Application.ActiveSheet` to `Sh`. And change `ByVal Souce as Range` to `ByVal Target As Range`.

Comment: I've added `Application.EnableEvents = True` to the Immediate window, when I type `Application.ActiveSheet = Sh` it says `Run-time error '438: Object does not support this property or method`?

Comment: In the line `Set WorkRng = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("B:B"), Target)`.

Comment: Ok, changed to `Set WorkRng = Intersect(Sh.Range("B:B"), Target)` but hwen i fill column B it generates `Run-time error '424': Object Required`

Comment: Did you change `ByVal Source as Range` to `ByVal Target as Range`? Also - add `Option Explicit` to the top of the module.

Comment: I just did...missed that the first time. It's working! Thank you! Wow I missed a lot of stuff :/ You should post an answer for the rep if you want!

Comment: One last question for you if you know, after testing I made it a protected sheet but got a runtime error upon testing again. After turning off the protection (back to original state) it does not work again now? Any idea why this happens?

Comment: @55thSwiss - because on an error, events don't get re-enabled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of changes:

1) First, you need(ed) to change to the *workbook* level event: the [`Workbook.SheetChange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.sheetchange) event.

2) Then change `Application.ActiveSheet` to `Sh`.

3) Make sure that the parameter is named `Target` if you're using `Target` within the code body.

4) Add some error handling to make sure events always get re-enabled:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, _
                                 ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim xOffsetColumn As Integer
    Set WorkRng = Intersect(Sh.Range("B:B"), Target)
    xOffsetColumn = -1
    If Not WorkRng Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo SafeExit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each Rng In WorkRng
            If Not VBA.IsEmpty(Rng.Value) Then
                Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).Value = Now
                Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy, hh:mm:ss"
            Else
                Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).ClearContents
            End If
        Next
    End If

SafeExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Something for you to consider (if you desire so) is to catch `Now` before you `Loop` to prevent different values. In such case you might not even want a loop at all. Consider to replace:

```
For Each Rng In WorkRng
    If Not VBA.IsEmpty(Rng.Value) Then
        Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).Value = Now
        Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy, hh:mm:ss"
    Else
        Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).ClearContents
    End If
Next
```

With:

```
'Non empty cells with constants
If Application.CountA(WorkRng) > 0 Then
    Set Rng = WorkRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Offset(0, -1)
    Rng.Value = Now
    Rng.NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy, hh:mm:ss"
End If
```

And:

```
'Empty Cells
If Application.CountBlank(WorkRng) > 0 Then
    WorkRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Offset(0, -1).ClearContents
End If
```

You could implement this within the answer given by @BigBen if you will.

Comment: A slight wrinkle that I thought of while responding to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58883891/fill-cells-based-on-value-in-adjacent-cell). You'd need to handle the possibility of a formula being entered in column B too, right?

Comment: Yes you would, but since OP was using `IsEmpty` I thought it would be fine. @BigBen

Comment: Yeah I'm guessing so too, it was just from that other question (when OP was in fact using formulas instead of values) that I had the idea :) Still wish I could upvote another time (plus I don't see how my answer merits as many votes as it got).

Comment: It's all good @Bigben. Your answer answers Op's question therefor worthy upvotes. I'll have a look at the linked answer tomorrow if you wish. Maybe we can come up with something =). I see u used `Evaluate` to return the array wich would be my goto also at first glance.