# Copy cell from filtered range, where is only one row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy data from column in filtered range. The number of filtered rows is always different. First row is header.

I'm using this

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("N2:N" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("N" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
```

This works fine, when the number of filtered rows is bigger than 1. But when there's only one filtered row (and it should be N2:N2), it will copy the whole used range.

Thanks for advice.

Comment: `AutoFilter` won't work well when there is no hits (you should filter from `N1` > assuming its the header). Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58889516/9758194) post gives you some insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test to ensure that there are more visible rows then the Header Row before copying your range. Set your range to a variable, then count the number of visible cells in the range to ensure there are rows to copy. Also, as JvdV pointed you should use `N1` as the start. When copying visible cells in a range you should always use `Offset` to ensure you don't copy the Header Row, and `Resize` to ensure you don't copy the blank cell at the bottom due to the Offset. Here is a basic example of how to accomplish your task.

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("D1:D" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("D" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    If rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count > 1 Then
        rng.Resize(rng.Cells.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    End If
```

Comment: Works even better in my case. Thanks you too.

Answer (score 1):

In order to correctly work with filtered data, you should follow this pattern:

```
Sub FilterRange()

    Dim rngTable As Range    '//Holds: header + data
    Dim rngData As Range     '//Holds: only data
    Dim rngFiltered As Range '//Holds: filtered range

    '// Our range (data + header)
    Set rngTable = [N1:N100]

    '// Get data only
    With rngTable
        Set rngData = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1)
    End With

    '// Filter range
    rngTable.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="1"

    '// Catch error if no values are filtered
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngFiltered = rngData.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    '// Check if filtering was successful
    If Err = 0 Then
        '// Do some actions (for instance, copy to Sheet2)
        rngFiltered.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1)
    Else
        '// No filtered range
    End If

    '// Get back to error raising
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Comment: But what if I want to copy data only from one column? (Means one cell, beacuse it will filter only one row)

Comment: @sproust If you need first cell from filtered range, then you can call: `Set rngFirstCell = rngFiltered(1)` (if you have one column).

Comment: @sproust If you have, say, five columns and you need to get first cell from third column, then: `Set rngFirstCell = rngFiltered.Cells(1, 3)`.