# Delete any row that doesn't contain a date in column A

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook where I want to delete all rows in Sheet "Paste MyStock" column A that don't contain a date and then paste a formula and autofill to the last row.

The code works, however, it won't go through all rows. It suddenly stops after 2-3 rows and I have to run the macro several times. Why is this and how do I fix it?

This is my code:

```
Sub del_row_not_date()

Dim i As Integer
Dim MyStock As Worksheet
Dim Pivot As Worksheet
Dim Dta As Worksheet

Set MyStock = Sheets("Paste MyStock")
Set Formula = MyStock.Range("O1")
Set PasteFormula = MyStock.Range("N2")

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

LastRow = MyStock.Cells(MyStock.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow
    If IsDate(MyStock.Cells(i, 1)) = False Then
        MyStock.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next

Formula.Copy
PasteFormula.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

PasteFormula.AutoFill Destination:=MyStock.Range("N2:N" & LastRow)

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With   

End Sub
```

Comment: If you need to filter some range by some values and delete filtered rows, you can use filter. Follow my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59628305/3187033) where I explain how to properly filter the range. In the end, you just need to call `rngFiltered.EntireRow.Delete`. Deleting using filter is much faster than of a loop.

Answer (score 0):

When deleting, loop from the bottom up, otherwise your loop will inadvertently skip rows after deleting:

```
For i = LastRow to 2 Step -1
```

Also use `Long` instead of `Integer`; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long) why:

```
Dim i as Long
```

Comment: You can always do i=i-1 when row has been deleted, at the end of for loop

Comment: @4est it is not recommended to modify `i` within the loop.