# Copy Multiple Non-Adjacent Columns To Array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range

I'm trying to copy multiple non-adjacent (non-contiguous) excel columns to an array but it's not working. Below is what I've tried...

```
    Public Function Test()    
        Dim sh As Worksheet: Set sh = Application.Sheets("MyWorksheet")
        Dim lr As Long: lr = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
        Dim r1 As Range: Set r1 = sh.Range("A1:A" & lr)
        Dim r2 As Range: Set r2 = sh.Range("C1:C" & lr)
        Dim rAll As Range: Set rAll = Union(r1, r2)
        'Dim arr() As Variant: arr = Application.Transpose(rAll) <-- Throws Type mismatch error
        'Dim arr As Variant: arr = Application.Transpose(rAll) <-- arr Value = Error 2015
        Dim arr() As Variant: arr = rAll.Value2 ' <-- Only the first column (col A) is loaded.
    End Function
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18993915/get-values-from-union-of-non-contiguous-ranges-into-array-with-vba-with-a-simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you PEH, 
Great explanation which led me to the following solution:

```
    Function Test()
       Dim sh as Worksheet : set sh = Sheets("MySheet")
       Dim lr as Long : lr = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
       Dim arr () as Variant
       Dim idx as Long

       ' Delete unwanted columns to ensure contiguous columns...
       sh.Columns("B:B").Delete

       ' Load Array
       arr = Sheet("MySheet").Range("A1:B" & lr).value2

       ' This allows speedy index finds... Note, index(arr, startrow, keycol) 
       ' Will need to use "On Error" to handle key not being found
       idx = WorksheetFunction.match("MyKey", WorksheetFunction.Index(arr, 0, 2), 0)

       ' And then fast processing through the array
       For idx = idx to lr
          if (arr(idx, 2) <> "MyKey") then exit for
          ' do some processing...
       Next idx
   End Function
```

Thank you again!

Comment: Some hints: Might draw your attention to the fact that usually a function returns a function result and should be used that way. Furthermore you are on the safe side using always fully qualified range references (so you might use `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(...).Range(...)` or the sheet's Code(Name); note that `Sheet(...)` instead of `Worksheet(...)` can include shapes as well. - Btw, as you found PeH 's answer helpful, feel free to accept his solution by ticking the green checkmark *(including the possibility of upvoting any helpful answer)*.

Answer (score 3):

Since reading multiple values into an array like `arr = rAll.Value2` is only possible in continous ranges, you have to alternatives:

### Alternative 1:

Write a function that reads the range values area wise and merge it into one array.

```
Option Explicit 

Public Function NonContinousColumnsToArray(ByVal NonContinousRange As Range) As Variant
    Dim iArea As Long
    For iArea = 1 To NonContinousRange.Areas.Count - 1
        If NonContinousRange.Areas.Item(iArea).Rows.CountLarge <> NonContinousRange.Areas.Item(iArea + 1).Rows.CountLarge Then
            MsgBox "Different amount of rows is not allowed.", vbCritical, "NonContinousColumnsToArray"
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next iArea

    Dim ArrOutput() As Variant
    ArrOutput = NonContinousRange.Value2 'read first area into array

    'read all other areas
    For iArea = 2 To NonContinousRange.Areas.Count
        ReDim Preserve ArrOutput(1 To UBound(ArrOutput, 1), 1 To UBound(ArrOutput, 2) + NonContinousRange.Areas.Item(iArea).Columns.CountLarge) As Variant  'resize array

        Dim ArrTemp() As Variant  'read arrea at once into temp array
        ArrTemp = NonContinousRange.Areas.Item(iArea).Value2

        'merge temp array into output array
        Dim iCol As Long
        For iCol = 1 To UBound(ArrTemp, 2)
            Dim iRow As Long
            For iRow = 1 To UBound(ArrTemp, 1)
                ArrOutput(iRow, UBound(ArrOutput, 2) - UBound(ArrTemp, 2) + iCol) = ArrTemp(iRow, iCol)
            Next iRow
        Next iCol
    Next iArea

    NonContinousColumnsToArray = ArrOutput
End Function
```

So the following example procedure

```
Public Sub ExampleTest()
    Dim InputRng As Range
    Set InputRng = Union(Range("A1:A9"), Range("C1:D9"))

    Dim OutputArr() As Variant
    OutputArr = NonContinousColumnsToArray(InputRng)

    Range("A12").Resize(UBound(OutputArr, 1), UBound(OutputArr, 2)).Value = OutputArr
End Sub
```

would take the following non-continous range `Union(Range("A1:A9"), Range("C1:D9"))` as input,

[image]
*<sup>Image 1: The input range was non-continous A1:A9 and C1:D9.</sup>*

merge it into one array `OutputArr` and write the values as follows

[image]
*<sup>Image 2: The merged output array written back into cells.</sup>*

---

### Alterantive 2: Using a temporary worksheet …

… to paste the values as continous range, which then can be read into an array at once.

```
Public Sub ExampleTestTempSheet()
    Dim InputRng As Range
    Set InputRng = Union(Range("A1:A9"), Range("C1:D9"))

    Dim OutputArr() As Variant
    OutputArr = NonContinousColumnsToArrayViaTempSheet(InputRng)

    Range("A12").Resize(UBound(OutputArr, 1), UBound(OutputArr, 2)).Value = OutputArr
End Sub

Public Function NonContinousColumnsToArrayViaTempSheet(ByVal NonContinousRange As Range) As Variant
    On Error Resume Next
    NonContinousRange.Copy
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Different amount of rows is not allowed.", vbCritical, "NonContinousColumnsToArray"
        Exit Function
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    Dim TempSheet As Worksheet
    Set TempSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    TempSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    NonContinousColumnsToArrayViaTempSheet = TempSheet.UsedRange.Value2

    Dim ResetDisplayAlerts As Boolean
    ResetDisplayAlerts = Application.DisplayAlerts
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    TempSheet.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = ResetDisplayAlerts
End Function
```

Note that the alternative 2 is more likely to fail, because of the temporary worksheet. I think alternative 1 is more robust.

Comment: In the first option if you sum the total columns in the first loop over the areas, you can size the output array just once, and avoid the `Redim Preserve` in the second loop....

Comment: Yes, I also thought of this solution. I have no idea how bad a `Redim Preserve` in a loop affects the performance. So this might be an improvement in speed.

Comment: @PEH ad) performance: can't imagine such huge area numbers, but counting permanent `ReDim Preserve` within loop steps from 200,000 up to ~2M on my computer results in: 0,21M 0.1sec|0,43M 0.5sec|0,60M 1sec|0,85M 2sec|1,03M 3sec|1,30M 5sec|1,83M 10sec. - Btw you might be interested in my alternative solution to the current post via `Application.Index()` :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative solution via `Application.Index()` function**

Just for fun an alternative solution allowing even a resorted column order `A,D,C`:

```
Sub ExampleCall()
'[0]define range
    With Sheet1                   ' reference the project's source sheet Code(Name), e.g. Sheet1
        Dim lr As Long: lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim rng As Range: Set rng = .Range("A1:D" & lr)
    End With
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
'[1]get data in defined columns order A,C,D
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Dim data: data = RearrangeCols(rng, "A,D,C")
'[2]write to any target range
    Sheet2.Range("F1").Resize(UBound(data), UBound(data, 2)) = data
End Sub
```

**Help functions called by above main procedure**

```
Function RearrangeCols(rng As Range, ByVal ColumnList As String)
'Purpose: return rearranged column values based on ColumnList, e.g. Columns A,C,D instead of A:D
'[a]assign data to variant array
    Dim v: v = rng
'[b]rearrange columns
    v = Application.Index(v, Evaluate("row(1:" & UBound(v) & ")"), GetColNums(ColumnList))    ' Array(1, 3, 4)
'[c]return rearranged array values as function result
    RearrangeCols = v
End Function

Function GetColNums(ByVal ColumnList As String, Optional ByVal Delim As String = ",") As Variant()
'Purpose: return array of column numbers based on argument ColumnList, e.g. "A,C,D" ~> Array(1, 3, 4)
'[a]create 1-dim array based on string argument ColumnList via splitting
    Dim cols: cols = Split(ColumnList, Delim)
'[b]get the column numbers
    ReDim tmp(0 To UBound(cols))
    Dim i: For i = 0 To UBound(tmp):  tmp(i) = Range(cols(i) & ":" & cols(i)).Column: Next
'[c]return function result
    GetColNums = tmp
End Function
```

---

**Further solution** //*Edit as of 2020-06-11*

For the sake of completeness I demonstrate a further solution based on an *array of arrays* (here: `data`) using the rather unknown **double zero argument** in the `Application.Index()` function *(see section [2]b)*:

```
   data = Application.Transpose(Application.Index(data, 0, 0))
```

```
Sub FurtherSolution()
'[0]define range
    With Sheet1                   ' reference the project's source sheet Code(Name), e.g. Sheet1
        Dim lr As Long: lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim rng As Range: Set rng = .Range("A1:D" & lr)
    End With
'[1]assign data to variant array
    Dim v: v = rng
'[2]rearrange columns
    'a) define "flat" 1-dim array with 1-dim column data A,C,D (omitting B!)
    Dim data
    data = Array(aCol(v, 1), aCol(v, 3), aCol(v, 4))
    '=====================
    'b) create 2-dim array
    '---------------------
    data = Application.Transpose(Application.Index(data, 0, 0))
'[3]write to any target range
    Sheet2.Range("F1").Resize(UBound(data), UBound(data, 2)) = data

End Sub
Function aCol(DataArr, ByVal colNo As Long) As Variant()
'Purpose: return entire column data as "flat" 1-dim array
With Application
    aCol = .Transpose(.Index(DataArr, 0, colNo))
End With
End Function
```

**Caveat:** *This 2nd approach seems to be less performant for greater data sets.*

**Related link**

[Some pecularities of the `Application.Index()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51688593/excel-vba-insert-new-first-column-in-datafield-array-without-loops-or-api-call/51714153#51714153)

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind using arrays is to increase speed. Moving and deleting columns, as well as "for" looping slows you down.

I'm looking for a way to speed up one of my procedures from 120,000 µs to 60,000 or less.

The proposed solutions slow it down to 450,000.