# Get count of filtered rows and paste result in column

Tags: vba, count, advanced-filter

I have a worksheet with addresses and associated information including the state. I want to filter the worksheet by state and count the number of filtered rows, pasting that number of rows next to the state abbreviation in the adjoining column:
StateIN  RCount

I can get the code to autofilter and list all the states used in the worksheet, but am having trouble figuring out how to tell Excel that I want it to give me the number of filtered rows (minus the header row) for each state listed. I have tried several things, but this is essentially the code I am using:

```
'filter and copy individual state data from vqueue worksheet to state worksheet
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Dim x As Range
   Dim rng As Range
   Dim lastRow As Long
   Dim sht As String
   Dim LR As Long
   LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   

'specify sheet name in which the data is stored
   sht = "vqueue"

'change filter column in the following code
   lastRow = Sheets(sht).Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
   Set rng = Sheets(sht).Range("A1:AC" & lastRow)

   Sheets(sht).Range("J1:J" & lastRow).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("AD1"), Unique:=True

   For Each x In Range([AD2], Cells(Rows.Count, "AD").End(xlUp))
      With rng
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=x.Value
        Range("AE" & x).Value = ws.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count
                
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = x.Value
        ActiveSheet.Paste
      End With
   Next x
```

I'm not entirely sure I even have it placed in the right location in the for/with loop. Currently, I am getting a 424 Object required error. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Say when you filter a rng then you can get number of visible rows = `rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).cells.count/rng.columns.count` ... refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62099204/vba-array-of-filtered-data-to-populate-listbox)

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you just need to count the number os records that match a certain criteria, I would suggest using just formulas to handle with this case instead of VBA. You could use either `COUNTIF` or `COUNTIFS` functions. If you are using the most recent versions of Excel, you also have a `FILTER` function that could be used to generate the list of states dynamically based on specified criteria, and then use one of the count functions to obtain the record count.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I would do that, but this is part of a larger macro. I get a variable number is records each day but the same procedure must be used each day. I'm using VBA to automate the process as it is time consuming.