# Excel VBA - Populate a listbox using an if conditional loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgzCQ.png) as shown below which I want to use to populate a listbox.

[image: Table1]

I would like to loop through the table, column heading "Customer Name", to populate the listbox.

Please see the code below.

```
For i = 1 To Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Table").Rows.count
If Range("Table[Customer Name]")(i) = a Then frmFeee.lstCust.RowSource = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i & ": D" & i)
      
Next i
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Where is your freFeee? and are you trying to give rosource  for listbox as multiple columns?

Comment: If filter can be used, refer [populating list from filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62099204/vba-array-of-filtered-data-to-populate-listbox)

Comment: Hi Bharat, thank you for your comment. my frmFeee is just a framework that contains a listbox "lstCust". Yes I'm trying to have a multiple columns within my listbox.

Comment: What exactly is your question and how is your code not working?

Comment: You can use an advanced filter to copy columns you want to another page. Create a named range with the use of OFFSET function and then assign the named range to the RowSource property of your listbox.